# Text in android layout cut off, how to shift text to the right?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Ive been trying to fix this all day to no avail. I have a simple quiz app that asks the output of a code segment, but the text and code are too far to the left. I've tried fixing it in the layout by changing the margin but it messes up the color scheme.

Any ideas on to go about it?

Heres the xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1D6A9E"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.01" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView67"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_weight="0.01" 
        android:textSize="16dp"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_weight="0.04" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView2"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="31dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="RadioButton" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#CD211F"
        android:text="@string/str_next" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the class:

```
package com.interviewme;
/**
 * This class creates and holds the database table and its values
 * 
 */

/**
 * This class creates and holds the database table and its values
 * 
 */


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class DbHelper11 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //setting up database
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Creating the database name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "InterdjvniddjegdppddfdwgFdFApp";
    // Creating the tables namef
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST11 = "quest";
    // Creating the columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_CODE= "code";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //This string will be the answer
    private static final String KEY_OPTA= "opta"; //String for option A
    private static final String KEY_OPTB= "optb"; //String for option B

    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public DbHelper11(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    //making database
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase=db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST11 + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_CODE+ " TEXT, "  + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
                +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);        
        addQuestions11();
        //db.close();
    }
    private void addQuestions11()

    //adding the questions to the database

    {
        Question11 q1=new Question11("Which of these will cause a java programming error?",
                "A) float[ ] f = new float(3); "+
                "                                                                        "+
                "   B)float f3[ ] = new float[3];",                              
                "   A) float[ ] f = new float(3);",
                "   B)float f3[ ] = new float[3];",
                "   A) float[ ] f = new float(3);");



        this.addQuestion11(q1);



        Question11 q2=new Question11("2. What will be the output of the program? ",
                "public class Pet"+
                "                                                                           "+
                "  {                                                                        "+
                "                                                                       "+
                "   public static void main(String args[])                               "+
                "                                                                        "+
                "   {                                                                    "+
                "                                                                        "+
                "  class Dog                              "+
                "                                                                         "+
                "  {                                                                       "+
                "                                                                          "+
                "  public int i = 3;                                                       "+
                "  }                                                                          "+
                "  Object o = (Object)new Dog();                                            "+
                "                                                                            "+
                "  Dog dog = (Dog)o;                                                         "+
                "                                                                             "+
                "  System.out.println('i = ' + dog.i);                                         "+
                 "  }   ",

                 "i = 3", "compilation fails", "i = 3");



        this.addQuestion11(q2);
        Question11 q3=new Question11("What is the output of the program?",  
                 "for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)                                                 "+ 
                 "                                                                           "+ 
                 "  {                                                                        "+
                 "                                                                           "+
                 " switch(i)                                                                 "+
                 "                                                                           "+
                 "   {                                                                       "+
                 "                                                                           "+
                 " case 0: break;                                                            "+
                 "                                                                           "+
                 " case 1: System.out.print('one ');                                         "+
                 "                                                                           "+
                 " case 2: System.out.print('two ');                                         "+
                 "                                                                           "+            
                 "  case 3: System.out.print('three ');                                      "+
                 "                                                                           "+
                 "  }                                                                        "+ 
                 "                                                                           "+
                 "  }                                                                        "+
                  "   }                                                                       "+ 
                  "                                                                           "+
                  "System.out.println('done');                                                ", 
                  "Done",
                  "One two three done",
                  "One two three done");
        this.addQuestion11(q3);
        Question11 q4=new Question11("What will be the output of the program?",
                 "int i = O;                                                                 "+
                 "                                                                           "+
                 "  while(1)                                                                 "+
                 "                                                                           "+
                 "  {                                                                        "+
                 "                                                                           "+
                 "  if(i == 4)                                                               "+
                 "  {                                                                        "+
                 "                                                                           "+
                 " break;                                                                    "+
                 "    }                                                                                 "+
                 " ++i;                                                                       "+
                 "     }                                                                       "+
                 "  System.out.println('i = ' + i);                                              ",
                 "i=4",
                 "compilation fails",
                 "compilation fails");
        this.addQuestion11(q4);
        Question11 q5=new Question11("What will be the output of the program?",
                 "String a = 'newspaper';                                                     "+
                 "                                                                           "+
                 "  a = a.substring(5,7);                                                     "+
                 "                                                                           "+
                 "  char b = a.charAt(1);                                                     "+
                 "                                                                           "+
                 "  a = a + b;                                                               "+
                 "                                                                           "+
                 "  System.out.println(a);                                                   ",
                 "app",
                 "apa",
                 "app");

        this.addQuestion11(q5);

        Question11 q6=new Question11("6. What is the value of num after this code is executed?",
                 "Int num = 0;                                                                 "+
                 "                                                                                      "+
                 "  Int num2 = 12;                                                                       "+
                 "                                                                                      "+
                 "  While(num< num2)                                                                     "+
                 "                                                                                              "+
                 "        {                                                                              "+
                 "  num= numer+1;                                                                           "+
                 "          }                                                                            ",
                 "5",
                 "12",
                 "12");

        this.addQuestion11(q6);

        Question11 q7=new Question11("7. Look at the following piece of code."+
                  " What will be assigned to the variable if the code is executed?", 
                  "String string = new String (“PINK”);                                                 "+
                  "                                                                                        "+
                  "  Char fourthChar = string.CharAt(4);                                                    ",
                  "Throws " +
                  "StringIndexOutofBoundsException",

                  "K",
                  "Throws StringIndexOutofBoundsException");

        this.addQuestion11(q7);


        Question11 q8=new Question11("This code will generate a random number between what range?",
                      "double randNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 40 + 20);",
                      "20-60",
                      "0-40",
                      "20-60");

        this.addQuestion11(q8);



        Question11 q9=new Question11("9. What would the following code snippet output?",
                      "int sum = 5;                                                                          "+
                      "                                                                                        "+
                      " sum = sum + sum *5/2;                                                                  "+
                      "                                                                                        "+
                      "  System.out.println(sum);                                                              ",

                      "17",
                      "17.5",
                      "17");

        this.addQuestion11(q9);


        Question11 q10=new Question11("Analyze the following code",
                     "Circle c = new Circle (5);                                                                  "+
                      "                                                                                           "+
                      "  Cylinder c = cy;                                                                         ",

                      "The code has a compile error",
                      "The code is OK",
                      "The code has a compile error");


        this.addQuestion11(q10);

        Question11 q11 = new Question11 ("Does the return statement in the following method"+
                       " cause compile errors?",
                       "public static void main(String[] args) {                                                      "+
                       "                                                                                              "+
                       "  int max = 0;                                                                                "+
                       "                                                                                              "+
                       "  if (max != 0)                                                                               "+
                       "  System.out.println(max);                                                                    "+
                       "                                                                                               "+
                       "  else                                                                                         "+
                       "                                                                                              "+
                       "  return;                                                                                      "+
                       "      }                                                                                            ",
                       "Yes",
                       "No",
                       "Yes");

        this.addQuestion11(q11);
        Question11 q12 = new Question11 (" What is the output of the following code?",
                       "int z = 0;                                                                             "+
                               "                                                                                           "+
                        "  if (z < 4) {                                                                                    " +
                       "                                                                                           "+
                        "  z = z + 1;                                                                               "+
                       "                                                                                           "+
                       "  }                                                                                         "+
                       "                                                                                           "+
                       "  System.out.println('z is ' + z);                                                           ",
                       "z is 1",
                       "z is 2",
                       "z is 1");

        this.addQuestion11(q12);


        Question11 q13 = new Question11 (" Assume x = 6. Which of the following is true?",
                        "                                                                                               ",
                        "!(x == 6)",
                        " x != 5",
                        " x != 5");

        this.addQuestion11(q13);

        Question11 q14 = new Question11 (" What is the output of the following code:",
                         "public class Test {                                                                           "+
                         "                                                                                              "+
                         "  public static void main(String[] args) {                                                    "+
                          "                                                                                             "+
                         "  Object o1 = new Object();                                                                   "+
                         "                                                                                              "+
                         "  Object o2 = new Object();                                                                   "+
                         "                                                                                              "+
                         "  System.out.print((o1 == o2) + ' ' + (o1.equals(o2)));                                       ",
                         "False True",
                         "False False",
                         "False False");

        this.addQuestion11(q14);


        Question11 q15 = new Question11 (" Suppose an ArrayList list contains {"+
                "'blue' 'blue' 'pink'}. What is list after the following code?",
                "String element = 'blue';                                                                      "+
                "                                                                                              "+
                "  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)                                                       "+
                "                                                                                              "+
                "  if (list.get(i).equals(element))                                                            "+
                "                                                                                              "+
                "  list.remove(element);                                                                       ",
                "{'blue', 'pink'}",
                "{'blue','blue', 'pink'}",
                "{'blue', 'pink'}");

        this.addQuestion11(q15);


        Question11 q16 = new Question11 (" What is the output of the following code?",
                "char ch = 'G';                                                                                      "+
                "                                                                                                    "+
                "  if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')                                                                       "+
                "                                                                                                    "+
                "  System.out.println(ch);                                                                            ",
                "g",
                "G",
                "g");


        this.addQuestion11(q16);


        Question11 q17 = new Question11 ("What are the base cases in the following recursive method?",
                 "public static void example(int n) {                                                                  "+
                 "                                                                                                    "+
                 "  if (n > 0) {                                                                                        "+
                 "                                                                                                    "+
                 "  System.out.print(n % 10);                                                                          "+
                 "                                                                                                    "+
                 "  example(n / 10);                                                                                   "+
                 "                                                                                                    ",
                 "n <= 0",
                 "n > 0",
                 "n <= 0");


        this.addQuestion11(q17);
        Question11 q18 = new Question11 ("18. Study the following code:",
                "public class Example {                                                                                 "+
                "                                                                                                       "+
                "  public static void main(String[] args) {                                                              "+
                "                                                                                                       "+
                "  Number y = new Integer(3);                                                                            "+
                "                                                                                                       "+
                "  System.out.println(y.intValue());                                                                     "+
                "                                                                                                       "+
                "  System.out.println(y.compareTo(new Integer(4)));                                                      "+
                "                                                                                                         "+
                "    }                                                                                                    ",
                "The program has a compile error because y does not have the compareTo method",
                "The program compiles and runs fine",
                "The program has a compile error because y does not have the compareTo method");

        this.addQuestion11(q18);


        Question11 q19 = new Question11 ("What exception type will the following code throw?",
                "public class Example {                                                                                     "+
                "                                                                                                             "+
                "  public static void main(String[] args) {                                                                   "+
                "                                                                                                              "+
                "  System.out.println(1 / 0);                                                                                   "+
                " }                                                                                                             "+
                "                                                                                                                "+
                "}                                                                                                                ",
                "ClassCastException",
                "ArithmeticException",
                "ArithmeticException");


        this.addQuestion11(q19);

        Question11 q20 = new Question11 ("20. HashMap is an interface and Map is the class "+
                "that implements HashMap","CODE", "True", "False", "True");
        this.addQuestion11(q20);

    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
        //drop the table if it all ready exists
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST11);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    // Method to add the questions from the "Question" class
    public void addQuestion11(Question11 quest) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION()); 
        values.put(KEY_CODE, quest.getCODE());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());

        // Creating a row with null values
        dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST11, null, values);      
    }

    //Creating an array to hold the questions
    public List<Question11> getAllQuestions11() {
        List<Question11> questionList11 = new ArrayList<Question11>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST11;
        dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();

        //creating the cursor object
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Creating a looping to go through all rows and adding to the list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question11 quest11 = new Question11();
                quest11.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest11.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest11.setCODE(cursor.getString(2));
                quest11.setANSWER(cursor.getString(3));
                quest11.setOPTA(cursor.getString(4));
                quest11.setOPTB(cursor.getString(5));

                questionList11.add(quest11);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return quest list
        return questionList11;
    }
    public int rowcount()
    {
        int row=0;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST11;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        row=cursor.getCount();
        return row;
    }
```

}

(Ive tried to move the laoyout round in the dbHelper class too, but it didn't make a difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the textview is in a linear layout, use

```
android:layout_gravity = "Right"
```

if relative layout use

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

wrote the codes off head..put these in the textview.. and see if it works..let me know if this is what you looking for
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your text is very large, you could try to use a marquee effect:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use android:layout_gravity to align TextView in Linear Layout.